# Cryptic clue explanation: "Lock up devil is said to be in revolt"

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

I know the answer to the crossword clue ‘lock up devil is said to be in revolt’ is 'imprison' but I can’t explain the wordplay ‘devil is said to be in revolt’.

This clue was in *The Sun*'s 2-speed crossword ([No. 001042](https://feeds.thesun.co.uk/puzzles/crossword/20230129/52583/)).

Comment: Hi Graham and welcome to Puzzling - please can you mention the original puzzle where you found this clue? (For attribution purposes...) Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

I think the wordplay is as follows

> **IMP** is a devil and **RISON** sounds like (is said to be) risen - as in, no longer compliant, obedient or peaceful, i.e, "in revolt".